# Open internal files in Webview

Tags: android, file-io, webview

I have developed one application, in that I know the way to open files using webview + online and with using Third party application, but i want to open a internal files like .pdf, .doc, .xls, etc in web-view. without third party application and it must be offline. I also know there is way to open files in web-view + offline in IOS but can't find any solution in Android.

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I have been using WebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ url); to open files like .pdf, .ps, .doc etc

Comment: I want to open my documents without Internet. Do u have any solution for it? @r.bhardwaj

Comment: Is webview a good option for showing files without using any 3rd party app or there are some limitations?

Comment: Of course, it is a good option to shows all files without using third party API @Nainal

Comment: @Andrain But I have read that there are some bandwidth limits for showing documents in webview using gview. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23468989/reaching-the-bandwidth-limit-for-viewing-pdf-files-in-webview-through-google-doc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa]

Comment: @Nainal   I think u didn't get my question properly. I already said that I want to read file OFFLINE but gview is for online files and also a third party app.